# How to parse function attributes using libClang?

Tags: c++, libclang

I'm trying to parse function attributes using libClang but so far am unnsuccessful.

For example, I may have an attribute like this defined in a header.

```
#define __mobile__ __attribute__((mobile))
```

And in a separate .cpp file I have my function definition:

```
<template T>
__mobile__ void run(T int){...}
```

I've been spending the day toying with the libClang library and interfacing through it with C++.

So far I haven't been able to tell if the function contains such an attribute. The method clang_Cursor_hasAttrs returns 0 for the cursor run, which is of kind CXCursor_FunctionTemplate.